# Docker-compose with vue-vite + axios

Tags: docker, vue.js, docker-compose, axios, vite

i want to ask, why my docker can't find axios module. I can't find solution in the internet and documentations. This is my docker file:

Dockerfile

```
# build stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install all dependecies
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install


# Bundle app source
COPY . .
```

I have installed by "npm install axios --save" and without this flag.

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview --port 5050",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .vue,.js,.jsx,.cjs,.mjs --fix --ignore-path .gitignore"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "primeicons": "^5.0.0",
    "primevue": "^3.12.5",
    "vee-validate": "^4.5.11",
    "vue": "^3.2.31",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.13",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rushstack/eslint-patch": "^1.1.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^2.3.1",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.2.0",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "vite": "^2.9.5"
  }
}
```

Answer of docker-compose

```
frontedMatol | Failed to resolve import "axios" from "src/services/auth.service.js". Does the file exist?
frontedMatol | 2:13:05 PM [vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "axios" from "src/services/auth.service.js". Does the file exist?
frontedMatol |   Plugin: vite:import-analysis
frontedMatol |   File: /app/src/services/auth.service.js
frontedMatol |   1  |  import axios from 'axios';
frontedMatol |      |                     ^
frontedMatol |   2  |  const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/'
frontedMatol |   3  |  class AuthService {
frontedMatol |       at formatError (/app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-27bc1ab8.js:36435:46)
frontedMatol |       at TransformContext.error (/app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-27bc1ab8.js:36431:19)
frontedMatol |       at normalizeUrl (/app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-27bc1ab8.js:59840:26)
frontedMatol |       at async TransformContext.transform (/app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-27bc1ab8.js:59989:57)
frontedMatol |       at async Object.transform (/app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-27bc1ab8.js:36672:30)
frontedMatol |       at async doTransform (/app/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-27bc1ab8.js:55662:29)
```

I have to add docker-compose too:

```
version: '3.9'

services:

  postgres:
    container_name: postgresxx
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: xx
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: xx
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadminxx
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:-pgadmin4@pgadmin.org}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:-xx}
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
    volumes:
      - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    networks:
      - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

  maildev:
    container_name: mailDevXx
    image: maildev/maildev
    ports:
      - "1080:1080"
      - "1025:1025"
    networks:
      - spring

  backend:
    container_name: backendxx
    image: xx/xx-backend:latest
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=docker
    networks:
      - postgres
      - spring
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  frontend:
    container_name: frontedXx
    build:
      context: ../frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    working_dir: /app
    command: [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
    env_file:
      - ../config/env/server-developer.env
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ../frontend
        target: /app
      - type: volume
        source: node_modules
        target: /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - backend

networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge
  spring:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres:
  pgadmin:
  node_modules:
```

I changed names to xx to make it private.
So as i said, I am building project with docker-compose -f name_file up/build, and the server can't import axios. All of the "tutorials" said " change from ../axios to 'axios'. This can't help.

Also, i am working with visual studio code with docker extension, i went inside, and check yts package.json and lock. All of them has an axios dependency. So i am black whole.

THE MOST IMPORTANT is when i am building only vite, from frontend dir with npm run dev- axios works.

I can put repository flow, if you need it.

Comment: I deal with it. I deleted node_modules volume. axios did not exist in docker-frontend's node_modules, I don't know why, so if someone read it , i will be thankful